# Help with definition of derivative

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

My textbook says the definition is this:

$$\lim\limits_{\textbf{x} \rightarrow \textbf{x}_0} \frac{\|f(\textbf{x}) - f(\textbf{x}_0) - \textbf{T}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}_0)\|}{\|\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}_0\|} = 0$$

I am trying to learn how to use it on, say for example, the function $f(x,y) = xy$ at the point $(1, 1)$.

So we have:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{\|xy - 1 - \textbf{T}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}_0)\|}{\|(x,y) - (1,1)\|} = 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{\|xy - 1 - \textbf{T}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}_0)\|}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} = 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{\|xy - 1 - [y(x - 1) + x(y - 1)]\|}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} = 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{\|xy - 1 - xy + y - xy + x\|}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} = 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} \frac{\|- 1 + y - xy + x\|}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} = 0$$

But if I plug in $(1,1)$, I get an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Is everything correct so far?

Comment: Factor the numerator as $-(x-1)(y-1)$. Then I would recommend making the "polar" change of variables $x-1=r\cos\theta,y-1=r\sin\theta$, that should do the trick. And yes, everything looks right so far.

Comment: No, you need $\mathbf T =\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\end{bmatrix}$. You can't have a linear map that's quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Notice taking limit $x \neq 1$, and $y \neq 1$, but they get very close to $(1,1)$, and this is enough to get through the problem...

So starting at your last line: $|| - 1 + y - xy + x|| = |x - 1|\cdot |y - 1|$, so:

$0 \leq \dfrac{||-1 + y - xy + x||}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} = \dfrac{|x - 1|\cdot |y - 1|}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2}} \leq |x - 1|$. So:

$|x - 1| \to 0$ when $x \to 1$, and by squeeze theorem the middle term $\to 0$.

Comment: The error was far earlier...